# Is a free group a product of f.g subgroups of infinite index?

Tags: gr.group-theory, free-groups

Let $F$ be a free group, and let $H,K \leq F$ be finitely generated subgroups of infinite index in $F$. Is it possible that for the set of products we have $HK = F$ ?

Comment: I'm not sure about the votes to close - this seems a reasonable question to me.  Anyway, the answer is 'no'.  I'll try to write down an answer when I have time.

Comment: There are lots of ways to prove that $HK$ is a proper subset of $F$. For example, Theorem 1.1 in http://arxiv.org/abs/1308.3192 claims that there is a finite index subgroup $K'$ of $K$, s.t. $M:=\langle H,K'\rangle$ still has infinite index in $F$. Then, clearly $HK=\cup_{i=1}^k HK'g_i \subseteq \cup_{i=1}^k Mg_i \neq F$ (where $K=\sqcup_{i=1}^k K'g_i$).

Comment: Can you not use Marshall Hall's theorem to reduce to the case where one of the subgroups is a free factor?  If one of the subgroups is a proper free factor then you can use the finiteness of the Stallings graph of the other to show you can't reach every vertex in the Schreier graph using generators from the first factor.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It's actually easier to prove the stronger statement that there are infinitely many double cosets $H\backslash F/K$.

First, note that if $F'$ is a subgroup of finite index in $F$, with $H'$ and $K'$ its intersections with $H$ and $K$ respectively, then the natural map $H'\backslash F'/K'\to H\backslash F/K$ is finite-to-one. So we may pass to finite-index subgroups.

EDIT: (I was a little glib in translating from topology to group theory before.  Here's a corrected version of the final paragraph.)

Therefore, by Marshall Hall's theorem, we may take $F$ to be the fundamental group of a graph $X$ and $H$ and $K$ to be carried by embedded subgraphs $Y$ and $Z$, say.  But now it's easy. Indeed, let $a$ be a based loop not contained in $Y$ and $b$ a based loop not contained in $Z$.  Then the double cosets $Ha^mb^nK$ are all distinct.

Comment: How do you use M. Hall's theorem to find a single finite index subgroup $F' \leqslant F$ such that both $F' \cap H$ and $F' \cap K$ are free factors of $F'$?

Comment: Ashot, you need the observation that if $H$ is a free factor of $F$ then $H'$ is a free factor of $F'$. Topologically, this is obvious.

Comment: Actually, sorry, you're right, I should be a little more careful. The question is whether, given two embedded subgraphs in a graph $X$, one can find a maximal tree that restricts to a maximal tree in each. But this issue isn't really important.  One should just work in the graph $X$ (without contracting a maximal tree), and the same argument goes through.

Comment: This argument is not correct.

Comment: @AndreasThom, since there's already some discussion of how to modify the argument in comments, and you give no details of your critique, your comment is not very helpful.  Anyway, I've now edited the answer to fix my small mistake.

Comment: @Henry, how do you find $X$? That is the point that Ashot already raised. Is it really true that there is some finite index subgroup $F'$ such that both $F'\cap H$ and $F'\cap K$ are free factors?

Comment: @AndreasThom, as I said above, this is obvious from a topological point of view.  If $H$ is carried by an embedded subgraph $Y$ of $X$ and $X'$ is a cover of $X$, then $H\cap\pi_1X'$ is carried by the preimage of $Y$ in $X'$ which is, of course, embedded.  So applying Marshall Hall's theorem twice, we obtain a cover in which both intersections are free factors.  The corresponding cover is the graph $X$.

Comment: Ok, I see. Why not explain this in the answer?

Comment: @HJRW Once $H$ and $K$ are free factors, what is your algebraic choice for $a$ and $b$? some basis elements? How do you know that all the double cosets are indeed distinct? It looks like it can even happen that $a = b$...

Comment: Why not use the slightly easier version of this argument suggested in my comment to the question?  By Marshall hall you can assume that one of the subgroups H is a free factor. The covering space or Schreier graph associated to K has a finite core, the stallings graph. Outside this core you have infinitely many orbits of H so infinitely many double cosets. Both being free factors is not needed.

Comment: @Pablo, algebraically, you could take $a$ to be a generator in the free splitting for $H$ not contained in $H$, and likewise for $b$ and $K$.  You're quite right that it could be that $a=b$.

Comment: @BenjaminSteinberg, in fact, one doesn't need Marshall Hall's theorem at all. Geometrically, the point is that there are infinitely many different elevations of the the cover $X^H$ to the cover $X^K$ (in Wise's beautiful terminology).  On the other hand, writing it down cleanly for a questioner who seems to have difficulties with the topological point of view is another matter.  This seemed the best way to me.

Comment: Ok. Fair enough.

Comment: @BenjaminSteinberg does your argument also work for any finite number of subgroups and not just two (that is $H$ and $K$)?

Comment: @Pablo, mine does!

Comment: @HJRW and your approach can also show that the product of finitely many subgroups does not contain a coset of a finite index subgroup, right?

Comment: @Pablo, yes, that's right.